# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository.setMirroredRepositories(java.util.List)'

Tags: java, maven, drools

I am using Drools in my Java project. Below is the code for building the rules:

```
public class DroolsBeanFactory {
    private KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    private void getKieRepository() {
        final KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
        kieRepository.addKieModule(() -> kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
    }

    public KieSession getKieSession(String droolsFilePath){
        getKieRepository();
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

        kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(droolsFilePath));

        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
        kb.buildAll();
        KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();

        KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());

        return kContainer.newKieSession();
    }
}
```

This runs fine when running from Intellij, but when I run it from a jar file, I get the below exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository.setMirroredRepositories(java.util.List)'
        at org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem.injectMirror(MavenRepositorySystem.java:221)
        at org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem.injectMirror(MavenRepositorySystem.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.internal.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSessionFactory.newRepositorySession(DefaultRepositorySystemSessionFactory.java:235)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.newRepositorySession(DefaultMaven.java:365)
        at org.kie.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.init(MavenEmbedder.java:106)
        at org.kie.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:99)
        at org.kie.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:91)
        at org.kie.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:85)
        at org.kie.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.newMavenEmbedder(MavenProjectLoader.java:148)
        at org.kie.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:90)
        at org.kie.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:84)
        at org.kie.maven.integration.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:34)
        at org.kie.util.maven.support.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:110)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:598)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.init(KieBuilderImpl.java:155)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:221)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:195)
        at com.pkg.config.DroolsBeanFactory.getKieSession(DroolsBeanFactory.java:24)
        ... 7 more
```

Looks like there is some issue with maven packaging. But I am not able to understand how to resolve it. The failure is happening at `kb.buildAll()`

Comment: Could you share your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. There was a conflicting dependency that was importing `maven-artifact` version 3.0 jar. This jar did not have the method `setMirroredRepositories`. The problem got solved by excluding `maven-artifact` from the conflicting dependency.